# With Apple Watch 4, can I make phone calls without an iPhone?

Tags: bluetooth, apple-watch, call

I'd like to use Apple Watch Series 4 as a standalone device to make phone calls.

On an Apple Watch Series 4 Cellular, can I make a phone call via cellular network *without* my iPhone, which I'd like to leave at home, connected to it via Bluetooth or WiFi?

And, can I additionally make phone calls via a Bluetooth headset which connects directly to the Apple Watch 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Apple Watch Series 4 (along with Series 3) with support for Cellular can make a phone call without an iPhone but will need to be paired with it. Apple Watch Cellular comes with a build-in eSIM. It needs to be paired with the SIM card in your iPhone.

- [How to use your Apple Watch without your iPhone nearby](https://support.apple.com/HT205547)

Apple Watch Series 4 is typically expected to support all the phone call/cellular features of Series 3.

**Note**: Having an iPhone is a prerequisite for using an(any) Apple Watch. Thus, it's not possible to use an Apple Watch (any generation), without owning an iPhone.

Comment: Does it mean that once paired, I can leave my iPhone home and make phone calls with the Watch 4 on the go?

Comment: @LarsBlumberg Yes. That's true even for Apple Watch Series 3.

Comment: Ah, that's great. If you could highlight that in your answer, I could accept it.

Comment: Right now your answer reads as if it's not possible to make calls when away from the phone.

Comment: And how about connecting a Bluetooth headset without the iPhone being nearby?

Comment: Most (if not all) carriers charge extra for cellular watch.  In the US it’s 10/month + tax.